# Sharing data between child and parent windows (C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

**Scenario:**
Three forms: MainWindow, Positions, Calibration self-named (`MainWindow : Window` etc.)

MainWindow creates an instance of three objects:

- Vars: `Model Vars = new Model();`
- Positions: `Positions PositionsWindow = new Positions();`
- Calibration: `Calibration CalibrationWindow = new Calibration();`

A button in MainWindow is used to Show and Hide the child windows. Form fields in MainWindow update fields in class Vars.

MainWindow code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {

        Model Vars = new Model();
        Positions PositionsWindow = new Positions();
        Calibration CalibrationWindow = new Calibration();

        private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                PositionsWindow.Show();
        }

        private void TextBoxUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                Vars.TestVar = TestBox.Text;
        }
}
```

**Question:** How can form fields in the child windows update the parent form fields and/or fields in the class "Vars", i.e. passing data from child to parent and trigger an action in the parent form?

**Attempts:** A similar question suggested passing the main window `this`, example: `Positions PositionsWindow = new Positions();` however, this only works when the object is created in a method. At this point, `PositionsWindow.Show();` is no longer valid. i.e. it is only suitable for a child window created and closed in a single method.

Comment: @Ammar Salman your solution was best suited to the application, and  pointed out the key step of separating the object declaration and constructor.

Both solutions worked, thank you. I will keep these in mind for the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not really recommend initializing the variables before the constructor. Don't get used to that. 
I would change the constructor of each of the three Windows:

```
public partial class Model : Window{
    MainWindow MW;

    Model(MainWindow MW){
        this.MW = MW;
        // other constructor stuff
    }
}
```

Do the same thing for `Positions` and `Calibration`.

Obviously, you cannot use `this` when you are INITIALIZING the Windows BEFORE the constructor is called, because there is still no `this` to pass.

Therefore, in your MainWindow:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {

        Model Vars; // = new Model(this); <- the constructor was not yet called, there is no this
        Positions PositionsWindow; // = new Positions();
        Calibration CalibrationWindow; // = new Calibration();

        MainWindow(){
            Vars = new Model(this);
            Positions = new Positions(this);
            CalibrationWindow = new Calibration(this);
        }

        private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                PositionsWindow.Show();
        }

        private void TextBoxUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                Vars.TestVar = TestBox.Text;
        }
}
```

Edit: (to complete the answer to the question):
Now, if you want the Windows to change stuff to each other, just create functions in MainWindow that change stuff in each of the Windows. And with `MW` you can call these functions from any child Window

Comment: This will work but makes the child windows be tightly coupled with the parent window. That will give you more work to do if want to change how the parent is displaying data. Also becomes a problem if you want to use the same window on a different parent window.

Comment: @Adrian
`more work to do if want to change how the parent is displaying data`. How? The parent implements a method that changes what the child wants to change and the child can use `MW.whateverMethod()`. 

`the same window on a different parent window`. That's true, but the asker didn't say he wants that.

Anyway, for complicated applications, especially with multiple processes, this cannot work AT ALL. In such cases I would prefer to use WCF.
His application only has multiple threads (for each Window) and the answer should be enough.

Comment: Put it this way, if you want don't want to display a value from PositionsWindow on MainWindow anymore, but instead on the CalibrationsWindow, you will have to change PositionsWindow to take CalibrationsWindow in the constructor. Whilst you may not think that is much on its own, but multiply it by more windows and things become more difficult. So whilst I said this will work and does solve the question asked, it's just not the best solution. Because why do something twice if you can actually do it the right way in the first place. We all should be doing what's considered best practice.

Comment: @Adrian `you will have to change PositionsWindow to take CalibrationsWindow in the constructor` That's not true. You DON'T have to change the way you said. `MainWindow` holds instances of the three Windows. If they wanted to change stuff from each other, they can let their parent (`MainWindow`) do it for them without having to change structure. You only have to add the method that `PositionsWindow` is going to call on `MW` so that `MainWindow` applies some change on `CalibrationsWindow`.

Comment: Again, whilst that will work, it doesn't mean its that is the best way to solve the problem. Letting the parent do the delegation of information between child windows is giving it way too much responsibility to do.

Comment: @Adrian As I already said, I would use WCF or other communication techniques for complicated structures. When you have different processes with completely unrelated windows, then no answer on this question would even be partially correct.. It all depends on your application and what you would expect from it.

Comment: I agree with this being intended application dependent. Without making the question too long or too specific to see available options; this is best suited to my current case, where the child windows are simply being used for a number of textboxes to pass data to the main window.

Answer (score 1):

For me the best is using Subscribe/Publisher event-based way, here is the way to do it. (i recreate the code so that you can understand)

1) add an event publisher in your child windows.

```
public partial class ChildWindows : Window
{
    // the is the event publisher
    public event Action<string> ChildUpdated;

    public ChildWindows()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void updateParentBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // pass the parameter.
        ChildUpdated(updateTb.Text);
    }
}
```

2) Subscribe the publisher in your parent windows.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Model Vars;
    ChildWindows childWindows;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Vars = new Model();
        childWindows = new ChildWindows();

        //this is the event subscriber.
        childWindows.ChildUpdated += ChildWindows_ChildUpdated;
    }

    //do whatever you want here.
    void ChildWindows_ChildUpdated(string obj)
    {
        // Update your Vars and parent
        Vars.TestVar = obj;
        updateLbl.Content = Vars.TestVar;
    }

    private void openButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        childWindows.Show();
    }

    private void textBoxUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

3) In this case, when i type inside the textbox in my child windows, and press a button, it will appear on a label inside my parent windows.

P/S : i had changed the ParentUpdated to ChildUpdated. thanks to @Adrian for constructive feedback

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbMY2.png)

Comment: Whilst the pattern looks right to me and is also what I would do, I'm going to be a little bit pedantic and say that I would name the event as `ChildUpdated` not `ParentUpdated` as the parent is subscribing to when the child updates and then receives the changed value from the child.

Comment: @Adrian yeah i agree with you,thanks for the comment, i will adjust accordingly :)